# Oracle: Updating from self-join

Tags: sql, oracle

Given this table:

```
MODEL   RESULT  DATE    SECTION
AABBCC  10.5    1/1/2001    1
AABBCC  15.6    1/1/2001    2
AABBCC  42.2    1/1/2001    3
AABBCC  35.4    1/1/2001    4
AABBCC  82.1    1/1/2001    5
AABBCC  95.3    1/1/2001    6
AABBCC  76.5    1/1/2001    7
```

I want to make sure that for each section (for the same date/model), the result is always greater than or equal to ***any*** preceding section.

e.g. If row 7's result is less than row 6's result, I need to set row 7 equal to row 6's result.

Similarly, if row 5's result is less than row 2's result, I would need to set row 5's result to row 2's result.

I am able to find the cases where a higher section has a lower value than a preceding section using a self-join like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.MODEL as MODEL,
  t1.DATE as DATE
  t1.RESULT as RESULT_1,
  t1.SECTION as SECTION_1,
  t2.RESULT as RESULT_2,
  t2.SECTION as SECTION_2
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.DATE = t2.DATE AND t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL
WHERE t2.section > t1.section AND
      t2.result < t1.result
```

Which produces the following:

```
MODEL   DATE    SECTION_1   RESULT_1    SECTION_2   RESULT_2
AABBCC  1/1/2001    3   42.2    4   35.4
AABBCC  1/1/2001    6   95.3    7   76.5
```

I have attempted to MERGE the data like this:

```
MERGE INTO table new
USING (

SELECT 
  t1.MODEL as MODEL,
  t1.DATE as DATE
  t1.RESULT as RESULT_1,
  t1.SECTION as SECTION_1,
  t2.RESULT as RESULT_2,
  t2.SECTION as SECTION_2
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.DATE = t2.DATE AND t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL
WHERE t2.section > t1.section AND
      t2.result < t1.result 
) old

ON (new.DATE = old.DATE AND new.section > old.section)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET new.result = old.result;
```

but I get the following error:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of
>   rows in the source tables
>   30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
>   *Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
>              activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
>   *Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO table new
USING (
SELECT  MODEL,
        DATE,
        RESULT,
        SECTION
FROM (
SELECT 
  t1.MODEL as MODEL,
  t1.DATE as DATE,
  MAX(t1.RESULT) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MODEL ORDER BY t1.SECTION) as RESULT,
  t1.SECTION as SECTION,
  t1.RESULT as OLD_RESULT
FROM table t1)
WHERE OLD_RESULT != RESULT
) old
ON (new.DATE = old.DATE AND new.section = old.section and new.MODEL = old.MODEL )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET new.result = old.result;
```

Comment: My mistake, had a typo in there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Michael, one last question: Why does ordering the partition by t1.section change the results of max(t1.result). That is to say, why does it matter what order the resulting set is in, shouldn't the max value in that set be the same?

Comment: As you see Its analytic frunction `MAX(...) OVER (ORDER by ...)` [Analytic_Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm). And it change how should work aggregate